# Custom REST API endpoint returns rest_no_route when called via wp-json permalink

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I have the following code in my plugin, which during development has been working perfectly fine (called within `rest_api_init`).

```
// ?rest_route=bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_examples
    register_rest_route(
        'bridge/v1', '/(?P<participant>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/process/(?P<section>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)', [
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => [ $this->api, 'process' ],
        ]
    );
```

`<My URL>/index.php?rest_route=/bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables&replace&_wpnonce=<thenonce>` Works fine, regardless of whether they're enabled.

`<My URL>/wp-json/bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables&replace&_wpnonce=<thenonce>` returns `404 rest_no_route` when called.

These are both currently called by some generated buttons, which are generated using `rest_url( "bridge/v1/test-data/process/" )` (the `section` is appended to the string during display).

I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong here. I assumed I had to generate the full URL with `rest_url()`, but when directly called via the browser or API system the response is the same.

Comment: The problem is with the `bbe_sortables&replace` in the pretty URL. If you change it to `bbe_sortables?replace`, that should work.

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't think of that! Can you write that as a reply so I can mark that as resolved?

Comment: I'm also well-aware that this almost completely violates the REST approach. I'm gradually integrating them, but this was - as it always is - a short term quick fix solution. Obviously it bit me, but there you go.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "violates the REST approach"? But I already posted an answer for the original question.

Comment: Went on a ramble. This is a paginated request, and the page identifer was also an argument like this. I changed it to `test-data/process/page/2` to make it more clearer. Some of my older API practices were coming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `bbe_sortables&replace` in the permalink:

```
<My URL>/wp-json/bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables&replace&_wpnonce=<thenonce>
```

which results in an invalid route, where the supposedly query string is seen as part of the route:

```
/bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables&replace&_wpnonce=<thenonce>
```

(the valid route for that URL is `/bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables`)

and eventually the REST API [throws](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L975) the `rest_no_route` error.

To fix the problem, use [`add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) when generating the URL, to append the proper query string; e.g. with [`rest_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_url/):

```
$url = add_query_arg( array(
    'replace'  => 'VALUE',
    '_wpnonce' => 'VALUE',
), rest_url( 'bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables/' ) );

/* Sample $url output:

a) Permalinks enabled
http://example.com/wp-json/bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables/?replace=VALUE&_wpnonce=VALUE

b) Permalinks *not* enabled
http://example.com/index.php?rest_route=%2Fbridge%2Fv1%2Ftest-data%2Fprocess%2Fbbe_sortables%2F&replace=VALUE&_wpnonce=VALUE
*/
```

Or if you're certain that permalinks are *always* enabled on the site, then this would be fine:

```
rest_url( 'bridge/v1/test-data/process/bbe_sortables/?replace=VALUE&_wpnonce=VALUE' )
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll use your approach instead, as I'm currently just string-appending the arguments. This method is much more ideal.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, unless absolutely *not* necessary, I'd always use `add_query_arg()` when appending query strings to a WordPress URL which could be "pretty" or "ugly" (`index.php`-based). :)